# tableview cell child scrollview is not scrolling horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I am using `UITableView` view and inside the `UITableViewCell` I am using scrollview which will shows the image horizontally and its working fine with the dummy array values, After fetching the data from the server I will reload the `UITableView` in that case tableview is working fine but `UIScrollView` contents are not scrolling horizontally because of the `DispatchQueue.main.async`. I am not sure if the main thread is affecting the scrollview scrolls.

This is my `cellForRowAt` method :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:PostImageCell = tablView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostImageCell") as! PostImageCell
        cell.imageScrollView?.delegate = self
        let Padding:CGFloat = 10
        var Offset:CGFloat = 5
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let imagarray = self.UserDatas?.posts.app[indexPath.row].images

            for image in imagarray ?? ["string"] {
                let cardView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
                cardView.frame = CGRect(x: Offset, y: CGFloat(Padding), width: 150, height:                cell.imageScrollView.frame.height-10)
                cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                cardView = UIImageView(image: image)
                cardView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                [![cell.imageScrollView?.addSubview(cardView)
                Offset = Offset + CGFloat(Padding) + cardView.frame.size.width
            }
        }
        cell.imageScrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: Offset, height: cell.imageScrollView.frame.height)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
```

[image: It's my view]

Comment: Calling the `DispatchQueue.main.async` from main thread itself has no effect here. The main purpose of this async is that caller current thread won't wait for this requested thread task to be finished.

Comment: okay then how can I achieve this?

Comment: My point here wont solve your issue, the point i'm making dont call Dispatch.main.async from main thread.

Comment: I have commented the main thread, Now the last row table view cell scrollview Childs are not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippets in your code, Hope it would be helpful to you,

```
cardView.frame = CGRect(x: (CGFloat(i) * 150) + 5,
                                        y: CGFloat(Padding),
                                        width: 140,
                                        height: cell.imageScrollView.frame.height-10)


Offset = CGFloat(imagarray.count) * cardView.frame.size.width
```

Because, Offset allocation is making the conflict of your scroll view content size.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  Okay I will check with this code

Comment: It's also give the same result, no luck.. Actually my code is working fine for the design and with the dummy values, after getting the values from the server if reload the tableview its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Maybe the background download blocks the UI. Take a look at 
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            ...
            self.tv.reloadData()
        }
for updating the ui.

```
class PostImageCell : UITableViewCell {
var imageScrollView : UIScrollView!
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {     
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    imageScrollView = UIScrollView()
    imageScrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true
    self.contentView.addSubview(imageScrollView)
    imageScrollView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.contentView.frame.width,height: 150.0)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var myimages : [UIImage] = []
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
var tv : UITableView!
let PostImageCellid = "PostImageCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //My dummy images
    for i in 0...5 {
        let image = UIImage().WithSize(size: CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 150.0))
        myimages.append(image.drawText(text: String(i)))
    }

    tv = UITableView()
    tv.register(PostImageCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: self.PostImageCellid)
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(tv)

    //Now download a image in background
    ImageLoader.downloadImage(urlstr: "https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png") { image in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.myimages[0] = image
            self.tv.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tv.frame = view.frame
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("Cellforrow")
    let cell:PostImageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostImageCell") as! PostImageCell
    cell.imageScrollView?.delegate = self
    let Padding:CGFloat = 10
    var Offset:CGFloat = 5
    for image in myimages  {
        let cardView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        cardView.frame = CGRect(x: Offset, y: CGFloat(Padding), width: 150, height: cell.imageScrollView.frame.height-10)
        cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cardView.image = image
        cardView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        cell.imageScrollView?.addSubview(cardView)
        Offset = Offset + CGFloat(Padding) + cardView.frame.size.width
    }
    cell.imageScrollView?.contentSize = CGSize(width: Offset, height: cell.imageScrollView.frame.height)
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150.0
}
```

}

And some helper Classes for dummy images and for downloading a image from google:

```
lass ImageLoader {  
static func downloadImage(urlstr : String, complete: @escaping ((UIImage)->Void)){
    guard let url = URL(string: urlstr) else { return }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let data = data else { return }
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return }
        complete(image)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

}

```
extension UIImage {
func  drawText(text: String) -> UIImage {
    let color = UIColor.white
    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 16)!
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, scale)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: font,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color,
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    guard let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return self }
    return newImage
}

func WithSize(size: CGSize, color: UIColor = UIColor.clear) -> UIImage {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    color.set()
    UIRectFill(rect)

    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return self }
    return image
}
```

}

Comment: How do you reload the tableview?

Comment: self.tableView.reloadData()